# Unable to see Openshift application

Tags: openshift

I added a new openshift application. I followed the instructions and uploaded my code via git push.

The upload logs seem to be fine:

1)the ROOT.war got created:

```
remote: [INFO] Packaging webapp
remote: [INFO] Assembling webapp [opinion] in [/var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd
2ca700037d/app-root/runtime/repo/target/opinion]
remote: [INFO] Processing war project
remote: [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700
037d/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
remote: [INFO] Webapp assembled in [108 msecs]
remote: [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d/app-roo
t/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war
remote: [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
-------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
-------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 1:24.196s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 03 14:11:18 EDT 2014
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/91M
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

2) Deployment was a success

```
remote: + rm -rf /var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d/jbossews//work/
remote: ++ ls /var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d/app-root/runtime/repo/
/webapps
remote: + '[' 'META-INF
remote: ROOT.war
remote: WEB-INF
remote: css
remote: fonts
remote: img
remote: js' ']'
remote: + rsync -rS --delete /var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d/app-roo
t/runtime/repo//webapps/ /var/lib/openshift/542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d/jbossews//w
ebapps/
remote: + hot_deploy_enabled_for_latest_deployment
remote: ++ ruby_sdk latest_deployment_metadata.hot_deploy
remote: ++ oo-ruby -I/usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk -rruby/sdk -e 'include Ope
nShift::CartridgeSdk; puts latest_deployment_metadata.hot_deploy'
remote: + enabled=false
remote: + '[' false == true ']'
remote: + return 1
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: Found 127.4.212.129:8080 listening port
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://542ee542e0b8cd2ca700037d@opinion-expertviews.rhcloud.com/~/git/opinion.
git/
   e2a907c..08d3a44  master -> master
```

However, when I hit the url(http://opinion-expertviews.rhcloud.com) I am still seeing the 
"Welcome to your JBossEWS (Apache/Tomcat) application on OpenShift" screen

What am I missing?

**Solved:**

I was uploading my files incorrectly. Corrected way:

- I compiled my projects into a war file, put it into the webapps
  folder at root of the openshift git directory.
- removed the pom.xml
- file pushed the updated folder to my application
- Application now available at:

  http://app_name-namespace.rhcloud.com/app_name.

Thanks a lot for your help and guiding me, although it was stupid of me to miss these points

Comment: Did you remove or replace the index.html page that comes with the default application?  Or did you specify a new page for the root context? Also, did you do a git add to add all of your new files?

Comment: No I havent.. Any document on how to modify the default application with my own files?
I added my java content to the src folder and my web contents to the webcontent folder at root

Comment: Are you testing running your application locally to see if the war file works?  What java cartridge are you using?

Comment: I built a WAR file and added it to webapps folder. Now not seeing th e Welcome page anymore. I am seeing a blank page instead. TH .war file works fine for my local tomcat

Comment: What did you name the war file? if you want it at the root context (/) then you need to name it ROOT.war, otherwise it will be at app-domain.rhcloud.com/filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are deploying your war file with a name other than ROOT.war, you will need to visit your application at the context that is the same as the name of the war file you deployed.  For example, if your war file was named myapplication.war, your url would be http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/myapplication, to fix this, you can rename your war file ROOT.war, and your application would be available at http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/